# prove $\sum_iU_i$ is direct iff $\sum_i \underline{u}_i =0 \implies \underline{u}_i = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $U_i$ be a vector subspace for $V$ for $i = 1,...,r$

prove  $\sum_iU_i$ is direct iff $\sum_i \underline{u}_i =0 \implies \underline{u}_i = 0$

I'm taking a look at the proof, but it starts off like this:

$\implies$: Suppose $\sum U_i$ is direct and $\sum_i \underline{u_i} = \underline{0}$ then goes on to prove that all $\underline{u}_i = 0$, I'm confused at this approach, why can you assume that $\sum_i \underline{u}_i = 0$, Should we not only assume that $\sum U_i$ is direct, then go on to prove that $ \sum_i \underline{u}_i = 0$ then $\underline{u}_i = 0$?

Comment: what definition of direct some do you use?

Comment: what is $\underline{u}_i$

Comment: @ucf We say $\sum_i U_i$ is direct if $U_i \cap (\sum_{i\not=j}U_j) = \{0\}$. $\sum_i U_i = \{ \sum_i \underline{u}_i | \underline{u_i} \in U_i \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlights:

$$\sum_{i}U_i\;\;\text{direct}\iff \forall\,j\;,\;U_j\cap\sum_{i\neq j}U_i=\{0\}\iff \left(\forall\,x\,,\,\,\text{if}\;\; x=u_j=\sum_{i\neq j}u_i\,,\,\,u_k\in U_k\,\right.$$

$$\left.\text{then}\;\;u_k=0\;\;\forall k\right)\iff x=0\;\ldots$$